# Flatten list of dictionaries with multiple key, value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries with multiple KVP each

```
list_dict = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'sana'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'art'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'tiara'}]
```

I want to transform this into this format:

```
final_dict = {1: 'sana', 2: 'art', 3: 'tiara'}
```

I've been trying `dict` comprehensions but it does not work. Here's the best that I could do:

```
{k:v for d in list_dict for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `d.items()`, you can just access the `id` and `name` properties of each dict.

```
{d['id']: d['name'] for d in list_dict}
```

Answer (score 3):

for each element of the list you want the `d["id"]` to be the key and `d["name"]` to be the value, so the dictionary comprehension would look like this:

```
{d["id"]: d["name"] for d in list_dict}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
final_dict={} 
for dico in list_dict:
    final_dict[dico['id']] = dico['name']
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a few different ways you can do this. Here's a nice simple way of doing it using a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list_dict) # <- convert to dataframe
df = df.set_index('id') # <- set the index to the field you want as the key
final_dict = df['name'].to_dict() # <- convert the series 'name' to a dict
print(final_dict)

{1: 'sana', 2: 'art', 3: 'tiara'}
```